# Citation with page number needs to be (author year:page) for linguistics using LyX

Tags: lyx, citing, natbib, linguistics

I have set up a linguistics document in LyX with the following:

- Documents > Settings... > Document Class > Book (Standard Class)
- Documents > Settings... > Modules > added the Linguistics module
- Documents > Settings... > Bibliography > Citation Style Natbib, with Natbib style Author-year
- I have downloaded the LSA bibliography style language.bst.

My understanding from several sources is that I probably need to use Natbib if I want to have author-year citations.

I have created a BibTex .bib file. I have added the bibliography in the document, using the my .bib and language.bst already downloaded. This produces a beautiful bibliography, and I am quite pleased with it.

The problem comes with the citation. It produces author year, as promised, but linguistics documents want the format (author year:page). For example, (Longacre 1972:2). It is not offered as a citation style in the LyX Insert Citation dialog:

[image: LyX Insert Citation dialog]

I have downloaded the natbib documentation, but I don't see the answer there.

I have tried a work-around of adding the page numbers in the Text After field of the dialog. This results in a comma, space, and page after the year, instead of a colon: (Longacre 1972, 2). That's understandable, but it's not what I need. I have not found a way to change the comma and space to a colon.

I also tried a LaTeX command into the document:

```
\citet[2]{Longacre-1972}
```

This also returns a comma, space, and page after the year.

Finally, I tried adding \setcitestyle{aysep={ }} at various spots in the text and in the document preamble. This does nothing to change the output.

Am I missing something? Or does whatever code that produces the various citation styles need a modification?

Comment: By the way, we have a professional linguist on the LyX development team. If you ever ask a question that is specific to linguistics that you don't get an answer for here, please join lyx-users@lists.lyx.org and send an email there so they might see it.

Comment: Thanks, Scott, for info about the mailing list. Also as a linguist who has worked in software development world, I am glad to hear there's a linguist on the development team.

Comment: Yes we are lucky he is there. You can see some of his recent improvements related to linguists here: https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX22#modules

Answer (score 2):

I put the following command in the document preamble, and got the formatted output I wanted with the citation I added via the LyX interface:

```
\setcitestyle{notesep={:}}
```

Using the Text After field strikes me as a little bit of a kludge, but it works, and I'm not complaining.

This also properly formats this LaTeX command in the document:

```
\citep[2]{Longacre-1972}
```